# Do we "only accept questions where answers can be objectively judged as correct or incorrect"?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

A mod said that this site "only accepts questions where answers can be objectively judged as correct or incorrect".

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18474/was-trump-one-of-the-usas-most-liberal-presidents-ever-inaugurated#comment65989_18474

To what degree is that statement correct?

Comment: Obligatory reading: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) that not only contains the answer to this question, but also explains the reasons behind it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that I care one way or the other about subjective/objective in that case.  To me, the big problem with that question was that it was trying to establish a point.  That's a classic "..., am I right?"  Anyone posting an answer that disagreed would likely have received an argument from the asker.

Just to pick out one point, it argued that Donald Trump is pro free speech and that is a liberal position.  I could argue both parts of that.  Trump often says things against free speech.  In particular, he thinks that libel and slander laws should be stronger and put more of a burden on the speaker to prove the point.  And it's questionable whether liberals are pro free speech today.

The liberal positions on hate speech and campaign finance are completely reversed from where they were in 1990.  Citizens United was the ACLU position...until it became judicial precedent.  And what happened to "I hate what you say, but I'll defend to the death your right to say it"?  Nazis marching in a Jewish neighborhood was the liberal position.  Now [Hate speech is not protected by the First Amendment](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2017/apr/21/howard-dean/howard-deans-wrong-tweet-constitution-doesnt-prote/) is a liberal war cry.

I could write a whole answer on that single bullet point.  The question had what, fourteen bullet points?  If not overly subjective or a rant rather than a question, it's too broad.

Also

> Great subjective questions insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references

Says that subjective questions should have answers with objective criteria.  For example, if most voters for Trump self-identified as liberal (in reality, he did horribly with self-identified liberals), that would be an objective criterion.  As written that question didn't have an objective answer.  It would have been answered subjectively.

That seems to be what Philipp said:

> This website generally only accepts questions where answers can be objectively judged as correct or incorrect.

Facts and references can be judged objectively as correct or incorrect.

Again, I would have closed that question as expressing an opinion (a rant disguised as a question) rather than as subjective.

Answer (score 1):

That statement is incorrect. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Subjective questions are allowed, subject to several conditions, including:

> Great subjective questions insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references

Answer (score -1):

"Good subjective, bad subjective" seems to set an unreasonable high bar for a politics forum.

Questions upon which pros and cons can be explored and supported with references or authorities or well thought out reasons ought to be appropriate and allowed, even if they have no definitive answer in a field like politics.

Comment: This site isn't a "forum". Also, the type of question you describe in the second paragraph *is* allowed.